# Simulation diplays when triangles are cloned. Simulation does not work when I attempt instancing

Tags: javascript, three.js

https://codepen.io/whisperingShiba/pen/PoBreZz

Above is my code.  The only thing I think you would have to inspect is the JavaScript, and specifically the `function createPlaneList(num_pts,scene_in)`.  Inside this function I have created a switch by `const instance = true/false;` and `default is false`.

In the false state, the triangles are cloned, and the simulation renders in browser just fine.  In the true state, I fail to get a render.  From what some websites and ChatGPT has stated, instancing will greatly improve my simulation performance.

1. Why does instancing not work, when I match the pattern of ChatGPT and some other code I found online?
2. Does a simulation with geometry in this pattern receive performance benefit from instancing?
3. How can I further improve performance?

I'm very new to JS and Three.js so apologies for any obvious blunders

E: I think I have to use the `InstancedBufferGeometry()` constructor.  I did not realize this constructor existed and ChatGPT did not tell me about it, but the Codepen will be only half complete while I write the changes.

E2: https://codepen.io/whisperingShiba/pen/QWBXJod
I think it works, @prisoner849 was correct, I am surprised that the console did not throw an error and that I failed to catch the issue.  I'm not sure I got more performance, but I did learn a lot. E2-2, performance went up hugely, my computer is just chugging for some reason.

Comment: `randomScatter1()` function expects 4 parameters, but you pass 3: `randomScatter1(instance, box_size, .2);`, whereas the the last (fourth) parameter has to be the number of instances/points/objects.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks friend, why did javascript not throw an error to the console for me?

Comment: Welcome to javascript )